# how to use jq to group the parsing json results

Tags: json, rest, curl, jq

I am jq from the terminal , to parse and filter the rest api using curl

below the response

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "fxid": "03e401a",
            "id": "123"
        },
        {
            "fxid": "03e4099",
            "id": "567"
        },
        {
            "fxid": "867",
            "id": "666"
        }   
    ]
}
```

and. jq filter am using

```
.result[].fxid,.result[].id
```

and i got results as below

`"03e401a" "03e4099" "867" "123" "567" "666"`

but i want the filter results as follows , like grouping for each array element from json response , can anyone help me with this jq filter

```
"03e401a"
"123"
_________
"03e4099"
"567"
_______
"867"
"666"
```

Tried different jq filters , but nothing worked

Answer (score 2):

With

> ```
> .result[].fxid, .result[].id
> ```

you separately iterate twice over `.result`. Thus, `,` just then concatenates the two lists.

Instead, iterate once, use a pipe to update the context, and just then concatenate the two (or more) items. That way, the iteration happens outside the concatenation:

```bash
jq -r '.result[] | .fxid, .id'
```

```
03e401a
123
03e4099
567
867
666
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1oRu-5Ot7gZ)

To generate the blocks, just add more (static) items. For instance:

```bash
jq -r '.result[] | .fxid, .id, "---"'
```

```
03e401a
123
---
03e4099
567
---
867
666
---
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8wEo8evwYL-)

If you wanted to keep the JSON encoding for the values but not for the separators, use `@json` to re-encode them:

```bash
jq -r '.result[] | (.fxid, .id | @json), "_________"'
```

```
"03e401a"
"123"
_________
"03e4099"
"567"
_________
"867"
"666"
_________
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/c9El_p3tkB1)

Answer (score 1):

```
.result | map("\(.fxid)\n\(.id)") | join("\n------\n")
```

Will give

```
03e401a
123
------
03e4099
567
------
867
666
```

When running `jq` with the `--raw-output` option.

The idea is to concat `id` and `fxid` with a newline (`\n`) and then `join` each item with some horizontal lines wrapped on newlines.

---

Demo:
[image: [JqPlay Demo]]